# Loop through names and total sales for each name from a separate worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to go through a list of sales people, and take each name and loop it through the list of sales and get a total sales for each individual sales person. I am able to take any sales person and loop through the list to get me the total sales for that individual, where I am having issues is taking each sales person, then moving onto the next sales person.

On my spreadsheet, range(i1:i525) is the list of all 525 sales people. Column a has 10,000 sales amounts.

Here is what I have so far...

```
Sub find_tot()
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

x = 0
For Each t In Range("i1:i525")

    For i = 1 To 10000:
        If Cells(i, 1).Value Like t Then
            x = x + (Cells(i, 3).Value)
    Else:
        Cells(i, 4).Value = ""

        End If
        Range(i, 10).Value = x
    Next

Next t

End Sub
```

Comment: You're right, but this is only one part of a larger script...VBA was the most efficient way to get what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A native worksheet `SUMIF` formula should give you the results you need.

```
with sheets("Sheet1")
    .range("i1:i525").offset(0, 1).formula = "=SUMIF(A:A, I1, C:C)"
end with
```

I'm not entirely sure where column D comes in.